# php-fpm on macOS Monterey | Unable to access files on external drives

Tags: php, macos-monterey, mounted-volumes

I compiled from source (not via HomeBrew or MacPorts) php8, php-fpm and nginx on macOS 12.4 Monterey

I properly configured them.

Everything works fine except that PHP isn't able to read or write files stored on external drives.

I checked permissions on files allow r+w access to both php-fpm's and nginx's user/group

I allowed **full disk access** to php, php-fpm, nginx and launchd via System Preferences => Security => Privacy

I also tried disabling ownership on the external volume:

`sudo diskutil disableOwnership /Volumes/Storage`

`file_get_contents` still fails reporting **Operation not permitted**

This problem affects only code executed by the web server.

I moved the website diretory to the external drive and set nginx's root there: nginx is able to serve static content.

PHP Scripts invoked from the CLI can read and write files on external or remote volumes without any problem.

Given the above I assume the issue is with php-fpm but I can't figure it out.

---

**Update**

if I start **php-fpm** via terminal with `sudo php-fpm` then it is able to access files in external drives.

If the process is started by `launchd` it is not.

Comment: Did you check if there's anything in the log files? Error log, access log etc?

Comment: @GlennM nothing related to the problem on the logs

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the cause:

I have a LaunchDaemon that executes the bash script `webstack.sh`.

The script launches nginx and php-fpm and restart them in the unlikely case they crash.

The LaunchDaemon use `sh` to execute the script and `sh` on my system does not have full disk access.

`zsh` has full disk access so I changed `sh` with `zsh` and now php-fpm can access external drives.